# Append text to existing PDF File electron node.js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am generating pdf file from selected text in electron. But I want to append text in this pdf file but it overwrites the file each time. 
Is there any way that text will be appended to PDF file at end?

```
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
                  win.webContents.printToPDF(pdfSettings(), function(err, data) {
                            win.close();
                            if (err) {
                                //do whatever you want
                                return;
                            }
                            try{
                                fs.writeFileSync(filename, data);
                                console.log("save");
                            }catch(err){
                                //unable to save pdf..
                                console.log("unable to save" + err);
                            }
                        })
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **fs.appendFileSync()** instead of fs.writeFileSync